# Laravel PDOException(code: 0) failed loading cafile stream

Tags: mysql, laravel, nginx, openssl, lets-encrypt

```
/var/www/dashboard/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:70, PDOException(code: 0): failed loading cafile stream: 
`/etc/letsencrypt/live/dashboard.xyz.me/fullchain.pem' at 
/var/www/dashboard/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:70)
```

I get this error when I try to perform a DB operation from the public site. This is from a server that connects remotely to a dedicated database server. This server is set up with nginx and letsencrypt. However, every user-facing operation fails with this error: failed loading cafile stream.

What could I be missing?